# How to make an AutoHotKey script to fix my keyboard repeating key problem?

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey

I don't know how to program AutoHotKey but I think this would be easy for someone who does. My keyboard is defective and it's repeating the E key when I press it, against my will. I press E and it types EE, or EEE. It's the only key with this problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*e:: ;When 'e' is pressd (with or without modifiers like `Shift` or `Alt`)
Send e ;Send 'e' to the computer
Sleep 1000 ;Then delay for a duration of one second [change to taste]
return
```

---

Edit:

The code I have above "eats" all modifier keys when used with <kbd>e</kbd>, preventing combinations such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, etc. In order to fix this, we can just have the hotkey [Blind Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind) the <kbd>e</kbd>, which will stop it from suppressing the held down modifiers.

New code:

```
*e:: ;When 'e' is pressd (with or without modifiers like `Shift` or `Alt`)
Send {Blind}e ;Send 'e' blindly to the computer
Sleep 1000 ;Then delay for a duration of one second [change to taste]
return
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: There's a small problem, I am unable to type capital e, would you be able to improve it for that? thanks!

Comment: Oh, you are right, I completely forgot that it would prevent modifier keys (including Shift) from working with 'e'. I think I will do one better and fix the code so that it will still send all of the applicable modifier keys when the hotkey is used. Thank you for pointing out this oversight!

Comment: when I don't usee the E keey for some time it will just ignore when I type it until I typee it multiple timees... is there a fix?

Comment: There might- could you tell me how long is "some time" so I can try debugging it?

Comment: like more than 30 seconds... not a continuous typing....

Comment: Did this error occur for the old version of the script as well?

Comment: I will try using the old version again so that I can check it out

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that the problem also happens with the old version

Comment: Dang. I've using the script myself for the last couple of days (with my fully-functional keyboard), but I haven't been able to replicate the issue. The only thing I can think of for why this might be happening would be the keyboard is sticking or pressing the key down after long periods of unuse, requiring the first press to "unstick" the key and move it back up, and the second to actually press it again. But this even is not consistent with how the script should react in this case.

Comment: At this point, if you could possibly take a video of your computer and the behaviour that occurs (after long periods of non-use), and I might notice some other possible issues. Otherwise, it might just be better to get the keyboard checked out and cleaned/ repaired if that is possible.

Comment: i've tried setting the script priority to Real Time in windows Task Manager, but it didn't fix it. It's like the script "sleeps" when you don't use it for some time, then the first key press awakens it, but it only gets into action in the 2nd key press